# What does <ClassName> represent in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java development and I would like to know what does this statment represent:

```
private ArrayList<Drawable> images;
```

to new `images` `ArrayList`, with this `Drawable` something?

Thanks to all.

Comment: You can read that as "ArrayList of Drawables", i.e. a list implemented by arrays storing drawable objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). `images` is an `ArrayList` containing `Drawable` instances. You must always put `Drawable`s (or subclasses of `Drawable`) inside the `images` list and you will always get `Drawable`s back.